# Why is IntelliJ not finding partial keywords in file search?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I search for keywords inside a file in IntelliJ, I need to type the full keyword and it doesn't find partial words. For instance, if my document contains the word: `everyWhere`, when I type in `every`, it doesn't take me to the first occurrence of that word, so then I have to type in `everyWhere` for it to take me to what I'm looking for.

The version I'm running is: 14.0.1. Do I need to run an update? Any help/insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck `Whole words only` in the dialog.

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much! This has been puzzling me for a while.